# Webapp deployment fails with interface not visible from class loader exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-applications, weblogic12c

I have a fresh weblogic 12c server where I was trying to deploy a spring hibernate based Webapp and the deployment is failing with following exception:

```
<Mar 13, 2019 12:58:51,096 PM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "346350192983496" for task "0" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory is not visible from class loader"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory is not visible from class loader
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory is not visible from class loader
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:581)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:557)
        at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(WeakCache.java:230)
        at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:127)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:419)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I am using java 8 based web application, here are the versions of the different solutions/ libraries: 
Weblogic : 12.2.1.3.0 spring: 5.0.6 hibernate: 5.1.0

weblogic.xml:

```
<weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

<context-root>/iamws/adc</context-root>
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>false</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.joda.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.activation.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.activation.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.mail.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.mail.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.jboss.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: do you have weblogic.xml ?

Comment: Yes I have weblogic.xml in my war, added in the issue now.

Comment: adding java.persistence-api-2.2 jar in $DOMAIN_HOME/lib solved my problem but this seems to be a hack to me, any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding following to weblogic.xml:

```
<wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
```